# How to find files with multiple occurrences of a specific string

Tags: batch-file, cmd

I need help adjusting my batch script so it only picks up files with 2 or more occurrences of the word I am searching for. Currently this gives me all the files that has the word but I do not need the ones where the word occurs only once:

```
for /f "delims=" %A in ('findstr /i /M "myword" *.txt') do copy "%A" "C:\Desktop\newfolder"
```

How can I change this so it only copies the text files where "myword" occurs more than once?

Comment: Easy, if the words doesn't occur on the same line: `find /c` can do that ("count lines that contain the search string). Put a `for /f` around to catch the value. If two (or more) words can be on the same line, it gets ugly with cmd/batch.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
@echo off
for %%a in (*.txt) do ( 
  for /f %%b in ('type "%%a"^|find /c "myword"') do (
    if %%b geq 2 echo %%a    [actual count: %%b]
  )
)
```

Notes:

- `find /c` doesn't count occurrences of a string, but lines that contain that word (one or several times) which isn't the same but might be good enough for you.
- you might want to `find /i /c` to make it case insensitive (finding "myword" as well as "MyWord")
- `echo %%a    [actual count: %%b]` is for troubleshooting only, you want to replace it with the `copy` command in your final code.

Comment: I am confused, what is the copy command that will replace %%a and %%b also is %%a the same as %%b?

Comment: `%%a` is a file name, `%%b` is the number of lines containing the search string. So no, they are not the same. And "what's the copy command"? How about `copy "%%a" "C:\Desktop\newfolder\"`?

Answer (score 1):

As Stephan mentioned, you could use the find command in a for loop to capture the file name and the count of the word in question. You can then evaluate the count based on greater (GTR) than 1 and copy the file to the new location:

```
for /f "tokens=2,3 delims=: " %%a in ('find /i /c "myword" *.txt') do if %%b GTR 1 copy "%%a" "C:\Desktop\newfolder"
```

Comment: surely faster than mine, but not able to process files with spaces in their name correctly (maybe good enough for the asker though).

Comment: True. It might be a good idea to echo %%a first to verify it will process the files correctly for the needs of the asker.